# Why does auto-resized input get wrong initial width in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a text input field that should resize to fit its value. I've implemented it the following way:

```js
const ResizableInput = () => {
  const width = useTextRenderWidth({
    text: currentName,
    className: 'text-lg font-display',
  });

  return (
    <input
      type={'text'}
      value={currentName}
      style={{ width }}
      onChange={({ target }) => setCurrentName(target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

The `useTextRenderWidth` hook:

```js
const useTextRenderWidth = ({ text, className }) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const elem = useMemo(() => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');

    span.style.position = 'fixed';
    span.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
    span.style.top = '-100%';

    document.body.appendChild(span);

    return span;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    elem.innerText = text;
  }, [text]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isNil(className)) {
      elem.className = className;
    }
  }, [className]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(elem.offsetWidth);
  }, [text, className]);

  return width;
};
```

The problem here is that for the first render it gets the wrong width (just a bit smaller than needed). If I edit the value so that it does not really change (e. g. add and then remove a space), the width is calculated properly. It does properly recalculate the width even if Vite hot-reload happens. The generated element has correct width in DevTools, so I don't understand why it does not set the correct width at the first time.

Maybe there is some kind of event I can listen to catch the moment when the proper width is set for the element?

Comment: Have you tried `useLayoutEffect`?

Comment: @Unmitigated I didn't before, but now I tried with no success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case font loading was the problem. Hook was called before the font used was loaded, so the witdh was invalid.
The solution is to bind to `document.fonts.ready` - this promise resolves when all fonts are loaded, allowing to get the valid width.